# Paper's preservation (fixative not working)

Tags: paper, preservation, charcoal, fixative

Apparently, my (acid-free) paper (from 'SoHo Studio'; shown below) is yellowing, I have [Krylon Workable Fixatif Spray Coating](https://www.walmart.com/grocery/ip/Krylon-Workable-Fixatif-Spray-Coating-11-oz/20683596?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&wl13=807&&adid=22222222227017872817&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40941733712&wl4=pla-78879485912&wl5=9027304&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=120643079&wl11=local&wl12=20683596&veh=sem&gclid=Cj0KCQiAj9iBBhCJARIsAE9qRtDx4r76jbxQ4l7KLKfYqBcQwHnNidqvvFyohFXcurbtIT30FltT8pIaArYnEALw_wcB).

Obviously, fixatives prevent this issue to happen, what should I do?
Is there anything special I should do to my paper?
I don't think you can see the yellowing, but just trust me, it is yellow

[image]

Comment: cool drawing isn't it?

Comment: I've never had/heard issues with Krylon. Wondering maybe if it is an aging issue related to the age of the can itself. With quality control, and Walmart, it is hard to say how long an item was sitting on the shelf.

Comment: The fixative, itself, isn't supposed to yellow, but it doesn't prevent the paper from yellowing.

Comment: @Lyssagal, haha, nope, none of that, the can isn't even a year old. It could be true about how long the can was on the shelf though, but I don't think they allow the con to be there for a long period of time, however, fixative sprays last more than one year

Comment: @fixer1234, that's one of the primary porpuses of a fixative, isn't it?

Comment: @Isaac750, that isn't the purpose of a fixative.  There are some treatments that are supposed to minimize the oxidation of the paper to slow or stop it from yellowing.  The fixative is only supposed to not yellow, itself, or add acidity that would accelerate the paper's yellowing.  The fixative's purpose is to help bond stuff to the paper.

Comment: @fixer1234, well yea, but as you said, the fixative is also supposed to prevent from yellowing, its been just a few months since I sprayed it, this isn't suppose to happen

Comment: @Isaac750, that's the opposite of what fixer1234 said. The fixative does nothing for yellowing one way or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paper will yellow over time [because of lignin in the pulped wood](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/528/30).

Choosing an archival, acid-free fixative means that *the fixative itself* should not yellow over time. Unfortunately, the primary purpose of the **fixative** is to prevent smudging of the media that is on your paper. While it can *slow down* paper yellowing over time (by reducing the surface area of the paper that is exposed to air), it doesn't neutralize those oxidizing chemicals.

There are [ways to treat the paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/2011/30) to prevent the yellowing from getting worse, and you can also put it behind UV-blocking glass to protect it from further oxidization due to air and light. However, the current yellowing may not be reversible.

Comment: It was the sunlight then 

Comment: BUMP.  It could also be what the paper is mounted on/adjacent to or even what is floating in the air (cigarette smoke for example).